# How to get a paragraph to display fields labelled as odd/even?

Tags: paragraphs

I am using Drupal 8 and I want to get odd/even involved in a simple paragraph that has unlimited fields. Any clue what I am missing?

Comment: You add odd/even classes to the items of a field template and target the paragraphs inside by combining multiple css selectors.

Comment: So inside the paragraph template for my paragraph type?

Comment: As said you apply the odd/even classes to the items of a field template. Did you check the twig debug output?

Comment: `{% block paragraph %}

  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>

    {% block content %}

      {{ content }}

    {% endblock %}

  </div>

{% endblock paragraph %}`

So I add the classes here? Do you have an example?

Comment: No, you don't have a loop count here to check for odd/even. Do this in `{% for item in items %}` of `field--field-example.html.twig` (look up the field template name by enabling twig debug).